# Rocket Lab Archimedes engine injector and reusable charecteristics

Tags: engine-design, reuse, rocket-lab-neutron

From what has been said, the [Archimedes engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes_(rocket_engine)) isn't particularly ambitious WRT its ISP, however Rocket Lab have said it would be highly reusable, which *is* interesting. Does anyone know of any special features, mechanisms or general design principals that improve its reusability? Is it just a Sea Dragon approach - The engine is so ugly and its safety margins so large that it repulses the ocean (or reentry plasma)?